# The Difference between SQLite NVARCHAR and NVARCHAR2

Tags: sqlite

I don't know what is the difference between SQLite `NVARCHAR` and `NVARCHAR2` column.

I know that `NVARCHAR` is a Unicode-only text column, but what about `NVARCHAR2`?

Comment: Those are Oracle types. Why do they show up in an SQLite database?

Comment: You can name the data types for the columns anything you like in SQLite as long as they follow the rules set out for valid identifiers, try `CREATE TABLE test_table (id STACKOVERFLOW)`. See my answer and [the official documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) for the rules governing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference.

SQLite does not operate with strict data types like that, it has "storage classes".

If you check the [official documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) you'll find this rule, one of five used to determine which storage class to assign to a column from the data type you specify:

2. If the declared type of the column contains any of the strings "CHAR", "CLOB", or "TEXT" then that column has TEXT affinity. Notice that the type VARCHAR contains the string "CHAR" and is thus assigned TEXT affinity.

There are 5 rules in total but rule 2 covers `NVARCHAR` and `NVARCHAR2` and both will assign the storage class `TEXT` to the column.

Comment: if everything is TEXT then why they have created NVARCHAR and NVARCHAR2 data types?

Comment: Who are "they"? Where do you get that information from?

Comment: They=The authors of SQLite

Comment: But they (him) haven't. There is no such data types in SQLite.

Comment: SQLite expert tool have that data type for an SQLite database

Comment: But then that is a problem or question about that tool. SQLite does not have these types.

Comment: To be honest, I would be wary about an *expert* tool that obviously doesn't know how SQLite works. I can see in one of their examples that they have data types like `CHAR(40)` and `GRAPHIC`, none of these types exists in SQLite. The first will have text affinity, the other numeric affinity, either column can store whatever you want anyway.

Comment: very strange, because sqlite expert is still yet the best sqlite database manager which I found and working very well.

Answer (score 5):

**There is a difference**. In a way...

Here´s the thing:
As Lasse V. Karlsen says, SQLite does not act on the types you mentioned nor does it restrict the length by an argument passed in like in NVARCHAR(24) (but you could do check constraints to restrict length).

So why are these available in SQLite Expert (and other tools)? 
This info will be saved in the database schema (please check https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity and http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info) So should you bother to set these when creating a SQLite db as it will not be used by SQLite?

Yes if you will be using any tool to generate code from the schema! Maybe somebody will ask you to transfer the db to MSSQL, then there are some great tools that will use the schema and will map your SQLite to MSSQL in a blink. Or maybe you will use some .NET tool to map the tables into POCO classes, and these can also use the schema to map to the correct type and they will also use the restrictions and transfer these into data annotations on the properties that the columns map to. And EntityFramework 7 will have support built in for SQLite and their code generation will surely make use of the schema.