# NVARCHAR with variable length?

Tags: sql, sqlite, nvarchar

I want to create a table in SQL which has a string attr for Users of a website. How should I declare this attr, since names don't have a max length? Can I just leave the length empty and do it like this?

```
CREATE TABLE User(
id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
name NVARCHAR
)
```

Also, do I need to say NOT NULL for PRIMARY KEYS, or are primary keys already never null?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Whch dbms are you using? According to ANSI SQL `NVARCHAR` without length specified means length 1.

Comment: Primary key columns are implicitly NOT NULL.

Comment: @jarlh I just tried inserting an entry into that table with id as NULL and it worked. However, if I put NOT NULL it gives the warning correctly. Does SQLite require me to use NOT NULL even for primary keys?

Comment: You forgot the sqlite tag... AFAIK sqlite is less strict about rules...

Comment: "Less strict" - that's one way to put it :)  It's like the JavaScript of databases (not dissing it, it's phenomenal for its niche).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare length as **MAX** and primary key are automatically **NOT NULL**

```
CREATE TABLE User(
id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY 
name NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
```

Since you have later specified dbms as SQL Lite , the [**documentation**](http://www.sqlite.org/sessions/faq.html#q9) says

> What is the maximum size of a VARCHAR in SQLite?
>
> SQLite does not enforce the length of a VARCHAR. You can declare a
>   VARCHAR(10) and SQLite will be happy to let you put 500 characters in
>   it. And it will keep all 500 characters intact - it never truncates.

Comment: Oh, btw, is it NVARCHAR or NVARCHAR2? What's the difference between them?

Comment: which database are you using

Comment: SQLite #charLimit

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32071561/the-difference-between-sqlite-nvarchar-and-nvarchar2

Comment: Which dbms? (Product specific answer to a question without any dbms specified...)

Comment: @mhasan When I run the sql script I get an error cause of MAX. Should I define MAX somewhere?

Comment: No.. MAX is not for SQL Lite .. check edited answer documentation link

Comment: specify any size , SQL Lite is loosely typed i.e. wont truncate or throw error if size of string inserted exceeds column size specified

Answer (score 1):

> How should I declare this attr, since names don't have a max length?
>   Can I just leave the length empty and do it like this?

Yes, in SQLite you can just declare the column with any “text [affinity](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#type_affinity)” type name (`CHAR`, `TEXT`, `CLOB`, etc.) and it will store strings (or blobs) without length restriction (except for the global string length limit, which is 1 GB by default).

If you do want to constrain the length of strings, you can do it with an explicit `CHECK` constraint, like `CHECK(LENGTH(name) <= 100)`.

> Also, do I need to say NOT NULL for PRIMARY KEYS, or are primary keys
>   already never null?

Per the SQL standard, `PRIMARY KEY` implies `NOT NULL`.  However, SQLite has [a long-standing bug](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#constraints) that makes the explicit `NOT NULL` constraint required.

> According to the SQL standard, `PRIMARY KEY` should always imply `NOT NULL`. Unfortunately, due to a bug in some early versions, this is not
>   the case in SQLite. Unless the column is an `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` or the
>   table is a `WITHOUT ROWID` table or the column is declared `NOT NULL`,
>   SQLite allows `NULL` values in a `PRIMARY KEY` column. SQLite could be
>   fixed to conform to the standard, but doing so might break legacy
>   applications. Hence, it has been decided to merely document the fact
>   that SQLite allowing `NULL`s in most `PRIMARY KEY` columns.